# Strange drawing on iOS map when working with MKPolyline

Tags: mapkit, mkpolyline

In our app we are connecting GPS coordinates from the position of a user. When we are connecting the lines, it sometimes appears that there is a strange drawing happening. I mean the blurry red color thing on the right of the picture below. Did anyone experience this problem before? Might that be an iOS bug? By the way: It disappears when I reload the map. Management is asking me to fix it but I guess I have no influence here. Any thoughts?

[image]